# Can you lock on a local object in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have this snippet of code

```
private Templates retrieveFromCache(String name) {
        TemplatesWrapper t = xlCache.get(name);
        synchronized(t){
            if (!t.isValid()) {
                xlCache.remove(name);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return t.getTemplate();
    }
```

`xlCache` is a `ConcurrentHashMap`; my reason for synchronizing on `t` is that 2 threads could interleave where by the time Thread 1 verifies the predicate Thread 2 has already removed the object from the map and then a `NullPointerException` would be thrown. **Is my assumption correct as I know concurrency is one of the more difficult things to reason about**. And then to my original question, can I lock on `t` even if it's local?

And this is `private` method as well which gets called from a `public` method, does it make a diff?

**EDIT: MY original premise that a `NullPointerException` is thrown was incorrect as `remove()` returns `boolean` making synchronization moot; however, my question was of locking on a local object was answered.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` (and `Map`/`ConcurrentMap` in general) won't throw an exception if the specified key doesn't exist. That's why the `remove` method returns a `boolean`, to indicate whether or not anything *was* actually removed.

But yes, you can lock on the local variable. After all, you're really locking via a *reference* (and the monitor associated with the referenced object), not a variable - and the other concurrently running method would have the same reference.

Comment: In this specific case that may be true, but do you think synchronized on a local (non-field) reference is a good idea?

Comment: Personally I tend to lock on a privately held readonly variable, but it depends on the exact circumstance.

Comment: @Jon is my reasoning correct here given: "xlCache is a concurrentHashMap, so I get the wrapper from the map and then test if it's valid and then remove it or return the template from the wrapper"...is there the possibility of threads interleaving (since this is the whole reason for my synchronizing in the first place)...my mistake <pre>NullPointerException</pre> is thrown if the key is <pre>null</pre> not the value.

Comment: Exactly - so I don't believe you need any locking in the first place.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking since my original premise was flawed. Is there a case where things are timed such that `xlCache.remove(name)` would affect `TemplatesWrapper t = xlCache.get(name)` given diff threads are acting on the method?

Comment: The "get" may or may not return null, depending on which gets there first. You should account for that in your code.

Comment: Yup I mentioned this in a comment to @james below

Answer (score 2):

You can lock on any object you want.  However, in your case, it looks like you could solve it in a clearer and safer.

Synchronization should be as localized as possible.  Since you're getting the `TemplatesWrapper` from some unknown location, its possible that anyone can synchronize on it making it really hard to control the concurrency.  It should also be as obvious as possible just by looking at the code why something gets locked.

It would be better off to put the synchronization inside xlCache with something like `removeIfInvalid()`

Comment: xlCache is a concurrentHashMap, so I get the wrapper from the map and then test if it's valid and then remove it or return the template from the wrapper

Comment: I would just drop the synchronization all together then.  Removing an object that doesn't exist is allowed

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that will work just fine.

You can synchronize on any object in java so you code will work and will be thread safe.

Appart from the fact that you aren't checking for t being null. I'm guessing you have just missed that out of your code example?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to use the 2 arg remove method from ConcurrentMap (assuming t has a reasonable equals implementation).  then you don't need any synchronization:

```
private Templates retrieveFromCache(String name) {
    TemplatesWrapper t = xlCache.get(name);

    if (!t.isValid()) {
        xlCache.remove(name, t);
        return null;
    }
    return t.getTemplate();
}
```

Comment: I should add `if(t == null) return null;' to see if `TemplatesWrapper t = xlCache.get(name);` returns `null` and not `t`

Answer (score 0):

If remove(null) would call a null pointer exception, this seems reasonable.  If you don't expect collision to be a regular problem, you could also implement a possibly-faster version of the code, by just wrapping a try/catch around that instead of a synchronized.

In either case, I'd add a comment there to explain why you did what you did, so that a month from now, it still makes sense.